# How do you programatically change the source of an image whose name is ambiguous?

Tags: image, actionscript, flex3

How do you say or achieve container.child.source = image.png?

I have a hexagon map built by specifying width and height.  I draw a wireframe and place a base image for each hex into a canvas.  Next, the canvas listens for a mouse click.  I then run a calculation to determine which hex the mouse click was closest to.  My intent is to change the source of the image that the user clicked on.

I know that mapSlate.getChildByName(mapProperties[closestHex]['baseName']) is the intended hex but I can't quite get to the point of doing a .source as Flex doesn't know that the selected object is an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u are sure that `mapSlate.getChildByName(mapProperties[closestHex]['baseName'])` is the intended hex and that it is in fact an `Image`, can't you cast it into `Image` and change the source like:

```
Image(mapSlate.getChildByName(
    mapProperties[closestHex]['baseName'])).source = "image.png";
```

or

```
(mapSlate.getChildByName(
    mapProperties[closestHex]['baseName']) as Image).source = "image.png";
```

Comment: Awesome.  That is exactly what I needed.  I didn't know the syntax of how to classify it as an image.  As a workaround, I was removing the image, creating a new one and placing it.  It worked, but it was slow.  This method is much quicker.  Thank you.